# Why is my UPDATE ... WHERE ... ORDER BY .. LIMIT 1 statement taking so long?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, optimization, query-optimization

I'm trying to improve my query so that it doesn't take so long. Is there anything I can try?

I'm using InnoDB.

My table:

```
mysql> describe hunted_place_review_external_urls;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| worker_id    | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| queued_at    | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| external_url | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| place_id     | varchar(63)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| source_id    | varchar(63)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| successful   | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> show index from hunted_place_review_external_urls;
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                             | Non_unique | Key_name                                   | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| hunted_place_review_external_urls |          0 | PRIMARY                                    |            1 | id           | A         |     5118685 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| hunted_place_review_external_urls |          1 | worker_id                                  |            1 | worker_id    | A         |     5118685 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| hunted_place_review_external_urls |          1 | queued_at                                  |            1 | queued_at    | A         |     5118685 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| hunted_place_review_external_urls |          1 | worker_id_and_queued_at                    |            1 | worker_id    | A         |     5118685 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| hunted_place_review_external_urls |          1 | worker_id_and_queued_at                    |            2 | queued_at    | A         |     5118685 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| hunted_place_review_external_urls |          1 | place_id_source_id_external_url_successful |            1 | place_id     | A         |     5118685 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| hunted_place_review_external_urls |          1 | place_id_source_id_external_url_successful |            2 | source_id    | A         |     5118685 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| hunted_place_review_external_urls |          1 | place_id_source_id_external_url_successful |            3 | external_url | A         |     5118685 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| hunted_place_review_external_urls |          1 | place_id_source_id_external_url_successful |            4 | successful   | A         |     5118685 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

My query:

```
mysql> select count(*) from hunted_place_review_external_urls;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  4217356 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.96 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from hunted_place_review_external_urls where worker_id is null;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   772626 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.27 sec)

mysql> update hunted_place_review_external_urls set worker_id = "123" where worker_id is null order by queued_at asc limit 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (4.80 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

Why is the update query taking 4s even though I have both single and composite index on `queued_at` and `worker_id`? This never happened before when the number of rows with worker_id = null was much lower. With ~200k rows instead of 780k rows, it would only take a few milliseconds.

Note the equivalent query with `SELECT` instead of `UPDATE` is extremely fast:

```
mysql> select * from hunted_place_review_external_urls where worker_id is null order by  queued_at asc limit 1;
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

My `queued_at` values are timestamps expressed in number of milliseconds, such as `1398210069531`

I've tried dropping my single indices on `worker_id` and `queued_at` but the problem remains:

```
mysql> drop index queued_at on hunted_place_review_external_urls;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (3.75 sec)

mysql> drop index worker_id on hunted_place_review_external_urls;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (3.75 sec)

mysql> show index from hunted_place_review_external_urls;
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table                             | Non_unique | Key_name                                   | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| hunted_place_review_external_urls |          0 | PRIMARY                                    |            1 | id           | A         |     5118685 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| hunted_place_review_external_urls |          1 | worker_id_and_queued_at                    |            1 | worker_id    | A         |     5118685 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| hunted_place_review_external_urls |          1 | worker_id_and_queued_at                    |            2 | queued_at    | A         |     5118685 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| hunted_place_review_external_urls |          1 | place_id_source_id_external_url_successful |            1 | place_id     | A         |     5118685 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| hunted_place_review_external_urls |          1 | place_id_source_id_external_url_successful |            2 | source_id    | A         |     5118685 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| hunted_place_review_external_urls |          1 | place_id_source_id_external_url_successful |            3 | external_url | A         |     5118685 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| hunted_place_review_external_urls |          1 | place_id_source_id_external_url_successful |            4 | successful   | A         |     5118685 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------------------------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Here's my `EXPLAIN SELECT` statement. I'm using an old version of MYSQL that doesn't support `EXPLAIN UPDATE`:

```
mysql> explain select * from hunted_place_review_external_urls where worker_id is null order by queued_at asc limit 1;
+----+-------------+-----------------------------------+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                             | type | possible_keys           | key                     | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------------+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | hunted_place_review_external_urls | ref  | worker_id_and_queued_at | worker_id_and_queued_at | 768     | const | 1587282 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------------------------------+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+---------+-------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)? This will tell you which indices the query is (not) using.

Comment: I'm using an old version of mysql which can't do explain update, but I did it on the explain select statement and looks like it's using the correct index. I've updated my question.

Comment: Stop doing this. `select *`

Comment: What happens if you split it into two queries: `SELECT @id := id FROM ... ORDER BY queued_at LIMIT` followed by `UPDATE ... WHERE id = @id`?

Comment: I was writing an answer related to @Kermit comment, but then realized the problem is in the UPDATE, Truthfully though, your count may be skewed as you are counting all columns in the table

Comment: @ECarterYoung `COUNT(*)` just counts rows, not columns.

Comment: True but the Count is Based on a Column.  As Kermit states, and I concur `SELECT COUNT (id) FROM hunted_place_review_external_urls` is not only faster but may return a different count.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, I've resolved this issue by splitting the UPDATE into two queries as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

This is your query:

```
update hunted_place_review_external_urls
    set worker_id = "123"
    where worker_id is null
    order by queued_at asc
    limit 1;
```

It first has to find the row use for updating, and that requires applying the `where` clause and the `order by` clause.  Either it does all the work (scanning the table and then sorting), or it uses an index.  The proper index would be `hunted_place_review_external_urls(worker_id, queued_at)`.  You can add more columns at the end, but these must be the first two columns, and in that order.

EDIT:

Given that the `select` is fast, try this version:

```
update hunted_place_review_external_urls toupdate join
       (select
        from hunted_place_review_external_urls
        where worker_id is null
        order by queued_at asc
        limit 1
       ) l
       on toupdate.id = l.id
    set toupdate.worker_id = '123';
```

I'm not sure why the indexes would be used properly here but not in the `update`, but hopefully this will work.

Comment: Is that a composite index? I believe this table already has that index from this query I used: alter table hunted_place_review_external_urls add index worker_id_and_queued_at (`worker_id`, `queued_at`);

Comment: I've also tried removing the single indices "worker_id" and "queued_at" but it didn't help.

Comment: That is strange.  Does it work for the equivalent `select` statement?  (`select * from hunted_place_review_external_urls where worker_id is null order by queued_at asc limit 1`)

Comment: Yes, the equivalent select statement is extremely fast (~0s). I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the Time of `Drop Index`, `Create Index` and `update`.
You may notice a correlation.

- When you are simple performing `SELECT` Queries, indexes are **USEFUL**, cause they speed things up.
- When you are performing `UPDATE` or `DELETE` Statements - Indexes are bad, cause they slow things down! Whenever you change a value of an indexed column, MySQL needs to rebuild the index for any subsequent row. (assuming you are ALWAYS fetching the oldest entry - that means: Reindex ALL reamaining 772625 Rows.)

Try to drop the index on `worker_id` and see the Update Performance. If worker_id is not indexed, the update will be way faster. (Finding the entry **to** update is still as fast as before, because it mainly depends on the sorting performed on the indexed column `queued_at` and a very small subset of unindexed `null` values on the `worker_id`, matching the desired `queued_at` value)

---

I just created a dummy db and tested your setup:
With 1.000.000 Rows and both - the single index on `worker_id` and the composite index on `worker_id|queued at`, a select looks like:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE ISNULL( worker_ID ) ORDER BY queued_at ASC LIMIT 1
```

and the performance:

```
Query took 0.3360 sec
```

Trying to modify the `worker_id` in the way you do, results in:

```
UPDATE `tbl` SET worker_id=1 WHERE ISNULL(worker_ID) ORDER BY queued_at ASC LIMIT 1
```

performance:

```
1 row affected. (Query took 7.9592 sec)
```

Droping both the indexes (single and composite) on `worker_id`, then the same query results in:

```
1 row affected. (Query took 1.4364 sec)
```

(generated 50.000 rows per insert, so they have the same date, so the index is not "perfect" for searching, so "real" data may perform way better.)

Comment: MySQL indexes are B-trees. An update should require reindexing the modified row, but but all the other rows after it.

Comment: But with updating the "oldest" entry on the `worker_id` index, he is basically changing the root of the B-Tree, therefore causing a full rearangement of all blocks if i'm not misstaken.